# How to set -fx-max-width to USE_PREF_SIZE in JavaFX css?

Tags: java, css, javafx-8

Im writing a JavaFX-8 application and was wondering if it's possible to set min- or max-width of (e.g.) a Button to `USE_PREF_SIZE` by css. The class `Region` defines `USE_PREF_SIZE` as `Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY`, but how to set negative Infinity in css?
The JavaFX Reference Guide defines `-fx-min-width, -fx-pref-width, -fx-max-width` as `<number>` and a `<number>` is defined with the following regex `[+|-]? [[0-9]+|[0-9]*"."[0-9]+]`
So maybe it is impossible?

I have tried (for fun) to assign the java way for negative infinity `-1.0/0.0` and the css-parser has accepted the value, but without the expected effect. May someone could explain why it doesnt prints a warning or an error?

I already know how to set `USE_PREF_SIZE` by code and i also know the hack to set min, pref and max to the same value, but i want to do it in a css file the dynamic way.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you can't actually do this at the moment... however the CSS parser *does* support [`Infinity`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8u/rt/file/b8e9909e6708/modules/graphics/src/main/java/com/sun/javafx/css/parser/CSSParser.java#l888)...

Sounds like they're be pretty open to adding support for it if you open a new bug (that's how [support for `Infinity` was added](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.openjdk.openjfx.devel/7224)).