# Could not resolve 'USE_COMPUTED_SIZE' while resolving lookups for '-fx-pref-width'

Tags: java, debugging, javafx

I have this warnings in a javafx project: it happens when via CSS we declare: `-fx-pref-width:USE_COMPUTED_SIZE`

```
ADVERTENCIA: Could not resolve 'USE_COMPUTED_SIZE' while resolving lookups for '-fx-pref-width'
```

Any idea how to fix it ideally via css declaration?

thanks!

Comment: more details please, may be some portion of your code

Answer (score 2):

Constants like `USE_COMPUTED_SIZE` is just a `static final` field declared by the `Region` class and its subclasses. `USE_COMPUTED_SIZE` is actually simply `-1`, so this value has been reserved for this purpose.

Unfortunately for `USE_PREF_SIZE`, this constant has a value of `Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY`, which cannot be parsed by the CSS parser. See [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26940341/how-to-set-fx-max-width-to-use-pref-size-in-javafx-css).