# using USE_PREF_SIZE in javafx css

Tags: java, javafx, styling, scenebuilder, javafx-css

## How to use USE_PREF_SIZE property in javafx css

I am having a problem in javafx css. that's i want to use property of `Min Height` to `USE_PREF_SIZE` in javafx using css, because otherwise i have to apply many time this property in scene builder.
How i do it in css...

Scene builder allow this property like this.

[image]

When i use this property `CSS Analyzer` shows this as `-Infinity` as a change as shown below.

[image]

i use this like in css.

> -fx-min-height: -Infinity;

but it's not working. also i also try:

> -fx-min-height: USE_PREF_SIZE;

it's also not working. any help or tricks (advanced)???

Comment: This question is answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26940341/how-to-set-fx-max-width-to-use-pref-size-in-javafx-css

Comment: That's says use Infinity. But this is used for Max_VALUE not USE_PREF_SIZE.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/constant-values.html#javafx.scene.layout.Region.USE_PREF_SIZE